# Kubernetes Workflow

Tags: docker, kubernetes, coreos

I have been using kubernetes for a while now.

```
$ kubectl version                                                                                    
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"3", GitVersion:"v1.3.0+2831379", GitCommit:"283137936a
498aed572ee22af6774b6fb6e9fd94", GitTreeState:"not a git tree", BuildDate:"2016-07-05T15:40:25Z", GoV
ersion:"go1.6.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}                                            
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0", GitCommit:"5cb86ee022267586db
386f62781338b0483733b3", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"", GoVersion:"", Compiler:"", Platform:""}
```

I usually set an Ingress, Service and Replication Controller for each project.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: portifolio
  name: portifolio-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.cescoferraro.xyz
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: portifolio
          servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: portifolio
  name: portifolio
  labels:
    name: portifolio
spec:
  selector:
    name: portifolio
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  namespace: portifolio
  name: portifolio
  labels:
    name: portifolio
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    name: portifolio
  template:
    metadata:
      namespace: portifolio
      labels:
        name: portifolio
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: cescoferraro/portifolio:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: portifolio
          env:
          - name: KUBERNETES
            value: "true"
          - name: BRANCH
            value: "production"
```

My "problem" is that for deploying my app I usually do:

```
kubectl -f delete kubernetes.yaml
kubectl -f create kubernetes.yaml
```

I wish I could use a single command to deploy, whenever my app is up or down. Rolling updates do not work when I use the same image,(I think its a bug on my kubernetes server version). But it also do not work when the app has never been deployed at all.

I have read about Deployments, I wonder how it would help me?

**Goals**
 1. Deploy if app is brand new
 2. Replace existing pods with new ones using a new image from docker registry.

Comment: When deploying your app you can reference a folder of .yaml files. When rolling updating then just reference the Deployment file.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think keeping all resources inside one single manifest helps you with what you want to achieve, since your Service, Ingress and ReplicationController are not likely to change simultaneously.

If all you want to do is roll out new pods, I would recommend you to replace your ReplicationController with a **Deployment**. Manifests have almost the exact same syntax so it's easy to migrate from standard RCs, and you could perform a server-side rolling update with a single `kubectl replace -f manifest.yml`.

Please note that even with a Deployment resource you can't trigger a redeployment if nothing changed in your manifest. `kubectl replace` would just do nothing. Therefore you could for example increment or change a tag inside your manifest in order to force the deployment, if needed (eg. `revision: 003`).

Comment: If all I want to change is the revision of my container (i.e. deploy new code without changing the infrastructure) I would need to alter the manifest file (and presumably check that into source control as an extra commit). Is that the common practice for code releases? kubernetes claims that it will automatically update `:latest` tag even if it is locally cached but I've found that this doesn't work unless, as you say, you change the manifest or take down the nodes and replace them (or let the replication controller replace them).

Comment: For what you're describing you need to set `ImagePullPolicy: always` inside your manifest. This will always attempt to pull the image before creating containers.

Comment: "If you would like to always force a pull you must set a pull image policy of Always or specify a :latest tag on your image." (http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/) Implied to me that one or the other were necessary. In my testing, adding `ImagePullPolicy: always` doesn't cause Kubernetes to pull the image unless there is either a change the the manifest of the pod is being created.

Comment: That's correct, the image is pulled when the container is being recreated, so it happens only when a pod is restarted or created. Therefore you have to trigger the deployment yourself somehow.

Comment: See this snippet for rolling update : https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13488#issuecomment-240393845.
You may want to perform edit on other objects (annotations for example). The other solution is to version your config-maps.

Answer (score 3):

As already written in the previous answer, it is recommended to use a Deployment instead of a ReplicationController for this.

Using `imagePullPolicy: Always` will only ensure that Kubernetes does a `docker pull` before starting new PODs. It does not force recreation of PODs when nothing in the Deployment resource changes.

I would suggest to add 2 things to your solution:

- Add a label to the Deployment with the value `CURRENT_DATE` as a placeholder value
- Add a simple shell script to your project which replaces the placeholder with the current date+time and then uses kubectl to apply the resources.

### Example Bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sed "s/CURRENT_DATE/$(date)/" kubernetes.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Then use this script for redeployment instead of calling kubectl by yourself.

This is only meant as a very simple example. When it comes to creating/applying/patching resources in Kubernetes, things tend to get more and more complicated by time. If this happens, consider using some more advanced templating solutions, e.g. by using Python and Jinja2.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a deployment for this. Create it the first time, and after that you only need to do `kubectl set image deploy/my-app app=user/image:tag --record` and you're good to go.

Doing that, you can also do cool things like `kubectl rollout undo deploy/my-app` or get history and status.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [Argo](https://argoproj.github.io).

[Argo](https://argoproj.github.io) is an open-source workflow engine for Kubernetes. It allows to define complex microservices-based application deployment using YAML in source repo and automatically re-deploy app on YAML change (e.g. on every commit to `production` branch) .